# Extracting data from BeautifulSoup with <script> and var

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following is part of the html code from a page from which I want to extract the "name" and "event_place". However, I have never seen data tucked into this complicated way before. Within the  tag, there is 'var person', and within it, the name appears under "personBestName", namely 'John Stuart'.

Similarly for 'event_place' which is under 'var person'... etc. The event place entity should be "B, Hamilton (city/cité), Ontario, Canada"

```
<script>

  var person = {"id":"p_14062397399","links":{"record":{"href":"https://familysearch.org/platform/records/records/9MFX-7VLY"},"persona":{"href":"https://familysearch.org/platform/records/personas/KH21-F11"}},"extracted":true,"identifiers":{"http://gedcomx.org/Persistent":["https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KH21-F11"],"$":["https://familysearch.org/platform/externalId/easy/1001080442645"]},"principal":true,"gender":{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Male","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Gender","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_SEX_CODE","text":"Male","resource":"http://gedcomx.org/Male"}]}]},"names":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/BirthName","nameForms":[{"fullText":"John Stuart","parts":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Given","value":"John","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Given","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_NAME_GN","text":"John"}]}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Surname","value":"Stuart","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Surname","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_NAME_SURN","text":"Stuart"}]}]}],"fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Name","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_NAME","text":"John Stuart"}]}]}]}],"facts":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/MaritalStatus","value":"Single","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/MaritalStatus","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_MARITAL_STATUS","text":"Single"}]}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Religion","value":"Presbyterian","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Religion","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_RELIGION","text":"Presbyterian"}]}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Nationality","value":"Canadian","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Nationality","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_NATIONALITY","text":"Canadian"}]}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Census","date":{"original":"31 Mar 1901","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Date","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"EVENT_DATE","text":"31 Mar 1901"}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Year","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"EVENT_YEAR","text":"1901"}]}]},"place":{"original":"B, Hamilton (city/cité), Ontario, Canada","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Place","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"EVENT_PLACE","text":"B, Hamilton (city/cité), Ontario, Canada"}]}]},"primary":true},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Birth","date":{"original":"1831","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Year","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_BIRTH_YEAR_ESTIMATED","text":"1831"}]}]},"place":{"original":"Scotland","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Place","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_BIRTH_PLACE","text":"Scotland"}]}]}},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Immigration","date":{"original":"1848","fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Year","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_IMMIGRATION_YEAR","text":"1848"}]}]}}],"fields":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Age","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PR_AGE_ORIG","text":"70"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/UniqueIdentifier","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER","text":"1001080442645"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/HouseholdId","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"HOUSEHOLD_ID","text":"66"}]},{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/RelationshipToHead","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"PR_RELATIONSHIP_TO_HEAD","text":"Head"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/RelationshipToHeadCode","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"RELATIONSHIP_CODE","text":"SELF"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/CollectionId","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"COLLECTION_ID","text":"1584557"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/EventDistrict","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"EVENT_DISTRICT","text":"Hamilton (city/cité)"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/EventProvince","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"EVENT_PROVINCE","text":"Ontario"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/EventSubDistrict","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"EVENT_SUB_DISTRICT","text":"B"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/EventType","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"EVENT_TYPE","text":"Census"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/Id","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"ID","text":"z002-z000067618"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/Page","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PAGE","text":"8"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/Pid","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PID","text":"11335440"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/PpqId","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PPQ_ID","text":"08-0278"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/PrAgeInYears","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PR_AGE_IN_YEARS","text":"70"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/PrRacialOrTribalOrigin","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"PR_RACIAL_OR_TRIBAL_ORIGIN","text":"Scotch"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/RollNumber","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Original","labelId":"ROLL_NUMBER","text":"CC1901_47"}]},{"type":"http://familysearch.org/types/fields/SortKey","values":[{"type":"http://gedcomx.org/Interpreted","labelId":"SORT_KEY","text":"z002-z000067618_0000066_11335440_1001080442645"}]}],"url":"https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KH21-F11","personBestName":"John Stuart","localizedGender":"Male","title":"John Stuart, \"Canada Census, 1901\"","personRecordTitle":"John Stuart","metadata":{"bibliographicCitation":"\"Canada Census, 1901,\" , <i>FamilySearch</i> (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KH21-F11 : accessed 14 August 2015), John Stuart, B, Hamilton (city/cité), Ontario, Canada; citing p. 8, Library and Archives of Canada, Ottawa."},"imageMeta":{"thirdPartyHostName":"","isExternalImage":false,"thirdPartyURL":"","imageURL":"","wikiCollectionURL":"/learn/wiki/en/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&format=json&srsearch=CID1584557"}};
```

I was able to extract the Name entity from **another part (not shown)** of the html which is from a tag and a specified class.

```
# coding=utf-8
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from unicodedata import normalize
Url = "https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KHR6-D6D"
Page = urllib2.urlopen(Url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Page)
Page.close()
x = Soup.find("h3", { "class" : "print-only print-title" })
sx = x.string.encode('utf-8')
k = sx.split(', "Can')
kk = k[0].split(' in household')
name = kk[0]
print name
```

Edits:

```
# Get other fields
rawJ = Soup.find_all('script')
J = str(rawJ[10])
J1 = J.split('var person = ')
J2 = J1[1].rsplit('var record =')
J3 = J2[0].rsplit(';', 1)

JsonText = J3[0]
#print JsonText

s = json.loads(JsonText)
print s["personBestName"]

# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: That's JSON. You can use the `json` module in python to read in easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That long string is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which roughly maps to a python dictionary. You have key-value pairs, such as `"id"` and `"p_14062397399"` respectively.

So I beautified the JSON [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xrisk/cd82c17eea833bf007ed/raw/79f5f9bfa33aadaa6beafecb32b74e878a8cd605/data.json) and you can easily see the key-value pairs and the nested structure. To extract the name and address you would do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import urlopen
import json

Soup = bs(urlopen('https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KHR6-D6D').read())

rawJ = Soup.find_all('script')
J = str(rawJ[10])
J1 = J.split('var person = ')
J2 = J1[1].rsplit('var record =')
J3 = J2[0].rsplit(';', 1)

JsonText = J3[0].decode('utf-8')


s = json.loads(JsonText)
print s["personBestName"]
for i in s["facts"]:
    if i["type"] == "http://gedcomx.org/Census":
        print i["place"]["fields"][0]["values"][0]["text"]
```

Comment: Thanks but what do I put as 's'? I tried s = Soup.find_all('script') as well as s = Soup, both gave me errors.

Comment: Thanks, though how can I automate the extraction of the Json portion from the entire script? aka removing the '<script> var person = ' part from the beginning and the same at the end. I am able to split the beginning, but the end is quite tricky.

Comment: I think I have figured out how to splice and extract the json text, but I got this error running my above edits code: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I tried but similar error for that line: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 699: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Hi Rishav, I wonder if there is something wrong with my python or bs settings, I copy, paste, and run your code and still got this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Hi again, I finally figured out the issues, your code is working, mine just didn't decode properly in my test editor (sublime text), if I run it with Python IDLE it works.

Comment: @KubiK888 I use Sublime Text too, and it works for me… I don’t think Sublime Text is a problem hehe.

Comment: Really? But I keep getting that error from running in Sublime, and it works perfectly fine in Python IDLE. For the latter it even works when I remove the '.decode('utf-8')' part from 'JsonText = J3[0].decode('utf-8')'.

Comment: @KubiK888 how are you running it from Sublime Text?

Comment: Just press F7 like I normally do for all python scripts. And press F5 in Python IDLE.

Comment: @KubiK888 indeed I am getting it too. Strange. I don’t know why.

Comment: Mind if I ask how you come up with the code for extracting event_place? I look at the json portion and it looks very crammed and so hard for me to see the hierarchy, I would like to learn how to do it myself next time. Thanks.

Comment: @KubiK888 sure! drop into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85048/teenage-territory) anytime and I’ll be glad to explain it to you.